# C++ Segmentation fault when I try to cout anything after reading a file to a 2D array of c-strings

Tags: c++, file

One part of a madLibs project I'm doing for my cs124 class involves reading a file and putting each word/phrase between spaces into a 2-dimensional array (`fileArray`) with each row comprising a different word. The problem is that after I read the file, every cout statement I make gives a `Segmentation fault` error.

I'm not allowed to use strings, everything has to be c-string or a char [ ].
The input .txt file has a max char limit of 256 and every word in the file has a limit of 32 chars. I'm using `testfile.txt` to test my code; might not be relevant, but the file just has the text:
`This is a test file to test the fileArray function in MadLibs project`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

#define WORD_CHAR_LIMIT 32
#define ARRAY_SIZE 256

void readFile(char fileArray[][WORD_CHAR_LIMIT]);

int main()
{
   char fileArray[ARRAY_SIZE][WORD_CHAR_LIMIT];

   cout << "this is a test\n";
   readFile(fileArray);
   cout << "this is a test\n";
   return 0;
}

void readFile(char fileArray[][WORD_CHAR_LIMIT])
{
   char fileName[ARRAY_SIZE];
   cout << "Please enter the filename of the Mad Lib: ";
   cin >> fileName;

   ifstream fin(fileName);
   if (fin.fail())
      return;

   char data;
   int i = 0;
   int j = 0;

   fin >> data;
   while (!fin.eof())
   {
      if (data != ' ')
         fileArray[i][j] = data;
      else if (data == ' ')
      {
         i++;
         j = -1;
      }
      j++;
   }

   fin.close();
}
```

The first cout displays to the screen as it should, but then after calling `readFile()`, the next cout produces `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` when I expect the same thing as the first cout:

```
[nbird11@LinuxLab02 ~]$ g++ project09.cpp  
[nbird11@LinuxLab02 ~]$ a.out  
this is a test  
Please enter the filename of the Mad Lib: testfile.txt  
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Are you sure the input is smaller than the buffer? What happens if you use a std::string instead of a char array?

Comment: @DetectivePikachu I'm pretty sure the buffer should be large enough to handle the input. I'm not allowed to use strings for this project so I'm not exactly sure what would happen or if it would even be helpful.

Comment: It would be helpful to rule out the buffer size, Its probably not the issue but I would try it just to rule it out.

Comment: Use `gdb` it will tell you the exact reason for the segmentation fault

Comment: @DetectivePikachu I tried making the array bigger in both directions, but nothing changed.

Comment: @Gillespie Sorry, I'm kinda new at this. How do I use `gdb` in a linux shell?

Comment: You just run `gdb <executable>` and then `r` to run it. Then after it segfaults type `bt` to see the line where it segfaulted. I would read a gdb tutorial, it will be an invaluable debugging tool for you in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace your whole `while` loop with:

```
while(fin >> fileArray[i]) ++i;
```

Note that `while (!fin.eof())` is not a good test. It will not be `true` until you've actually tried to read beyond the end of the file.

As for the reason for the segmentation fault it could be that you read `data` once and reuse it forever:

```
fin >> data; // here you read data

while (!fin.eof())        // will never be true since you don't read more than once
{
    // here you use data

    if (data != ' ')      // will always be true

    else if (data == ' ') // will never be true

    j++;                  // will just keep on going until you reach ARRAY_SIZE and then
                          // anything can happen. Undefined Behaviour.
}
```

So, you'll get that first character in every iteration in the loop and you'll soon go out of bounds. Again, replacing the condition in your `while` loop would help:

```
while (fin >> data)
```